# How do I resolve hibernate c3p0 throwing StaleStateException when checkoutTimeout is configured?

Tags: hibernate, c3p0

My hibernate configuration is:

```
.... <hibernate config of username,password etc> ...
hibernate.c3p0.min_size           = 75;
hibernate.c3p0.max_size           = 100;
hibernate.c3p0.timeout            = 3600;
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period   = 300;
hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts = 5;
hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay  = 10;
hibernate.c3p0.checkoutTimeout    = 50;
```

I added the last three configurations (acquireRetryAttempts, acquireRetryDelay, checkoutTimeout) recently.

Without these configurations I do not see any problems.

However, with these configurations I see StaleStateException only for operations that write to the database (no exceptions at all for any other database operations).

I want checkoutTimeout so that I can track all instances when my connection pool becomes devoid of free connections. Without checkoutTimeout my app will wait indefinitely for a connection -- even if the pool is devoid of free connections. I want to specifically avoid that scenario.

I set checkoutTimeout at 50ms by measuring the time required for getEntityManager() to execute. The p99.99 were under 10ms. The p100 were under 1250m; however, these were rare outliers (maybe 12 data points). The requests volume on average is 3000tps.

I noticed that setting the timeout value to be higher, at 500ms or 1000ms does not cause StaleStateException. I don't understand why.

Comment: hi. c3p0 doesn't throw anything like a StaleStateException. it'd probably be a good idea to include the stack traces you are seeing in your post.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's possible that there are some other c3p0 configurations that interfere with the checkoutTimeout and cause the StaleStateException?

Yes, you are right; I should have included stacktrace. I will share the stack trace once I ensure that it does not contain any confidential information.